# Clothing won't work with armature

Tags: armature

I've given my character a meta rig & I have successfully got the body to move with it, however when I tried to link the clothing to the armature it doesn't move. I've tried transferring weights & weight painting the clothing but it still won't work. Can someone help please :)

[image]

Here is my blender file if anyone wants to have a crack at it :)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Unfortunately no one will be able to effectively answer your question until you provide more details. You need to consider that while you have likely been working on your project for a while, we haven't and know only what you tell us. Please provide more details (perhaps screenshots/diagrams of the dilemma and the settings that you have tried or a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for us to look at to better see your problem. If you can add sufficient details, ping me with @pycoder, and I'll remove my down vote and look at your Q again.

Comment: @pycoder Hi I added an image of the problem. I would add more but this is the general problem. : )